# Clear values of type List in a HashMap

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am using HashMap to store the key/value pairs. The keys contain duplicates and the value is a List. I want to clear the values list whenever a new key comes. My code so far is

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer> > bandsMap = new HashMap< Integer, List<Integer> >();
List<Integer> erfcn = new ArrayList< Integer >();

for(int i=0 ; i<frequencies.length; i++)
    erfcn.add(frequencies[i]);

bandsMap.put( band_number, erfcn);
```

What I do here is that I have an array of frequencies and I add the values of the array to my List and then put the list to my Map. It works fine when the band_number is same.

Suppose if for the first 10 times the `band_number = 20`, it simply adds new values in the list and adds that list with `key=20` in my Map. But when the new key arrives it adds the new content to the old key as well.

Is it somehow possible to check for the key if it is the same as previous key, then simply put the list to the map, otherwise first clear the List and then add it to Map?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are only creating the `erfcn` list one time. Each `bandsMap.put` call is associating that same list object with all the different keys. Instead, you need to create a `new` list for **each** band_number. You also need to re-use the existing list for that key if it exists.

So, move this line:

```
List<Integer> erfcn = new ArrayList< Integer >();
```

away from the declaration of bandsMap. Declare it directly inside the function that adds the frequencies, as follows:

```
List<Integer> erfcn = bandsMap.get(band_number);
if (erfcn == null) erfcn = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Is it important to create new list for each band Number ?

Comment: The function where I am getting the frequencies and storing it in a List might be called 1000 times for the same band number

Comment: @UmairIqbal Yes, otherwise you only have one list object in total, and every key points to that same object with the same items. You need one list per band_number.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `List` for the key from the `Map` and append to it.

```
List<Integer> erfcn = bandsMap.get(band_number);
```

If `get(band_number)` returns `null`, create a new `List`.

```
if (erfcn == null) {
  erfcn = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: there is a need of checking if erfcn is null to create a new list, isn't it? :P

Comment: positively helped the OP ;)

Comment: I also suggest you check out Multimaps from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps).